# How to get all similar ids into an array with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm very new to JavaScript in general so having trouble with this. Working with Rails / jQuery / CoffeeScript. I'm adding a bulk add option to a form. The bulk add works however I'm also trying to save any fields that were manually filled. This is the code I have so far:

```
window.insert_bulk_fields = (text)->
  site = $('#website_link').val()
  links = text.split('\n').join('&links[]=').replace(/\s+/g, '')
  input_links = $("input[type=text][id^='website_rentals_attributes']").val()
  other_links = '&links[]=' + input_links.split(',').join('&links[]=')
  window.location.href = './new?links[]=' + links + other_links + '&site=' + site
```

Everything works except for

```
input_links = $("input[type=text][id^='website_rentals_attributes']").val()
```

which is only returning the first instance rather than an array of all those fields.

I've gone through similar questions on stackoverflow but I can't make this work.

Comment: this is what [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does... returns the value of the _first element_ in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) for this as you are dealing with a collection

```
input_links = $("input[type=text][id^='website_rentals_attributes']").map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try changing this to CoffeeScript syntax (this is my second day working on JS)